# I want to use CSS Hover but I can't run it

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

The page I prepared is a react project.

I'm rendering some information using the starwars api.

When I put this information in a different container, when I hover over it with the mouse, the relevant field is a different color and I want it to write the information I have given in it.

I tried a few things about it but without success.

You can see in the "snippet" what information I get from the api and how I print it to the screen.

My relevant CSS code is also in there.

I mentioned the part that I couldn't run in the comment line

I hope I explained correctly.

Thank you for your help in advance.

I print it on the screen like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../styles/Films.css";

class Films extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
    movieDetailsOpen: false,
    movieSelected: "",
    index: 0,
    page: 1,
    isLoading: false,
  };

  posterImages = [
    "CR90-Corvette.png",
    "stardestroyer.png",
    "Sentinel-class-landing-craft.jpg",
    "Death-Star.png",
    "Millenium_Falcon.jpg",
    "Y-wing.png",
    "x-wing.png",
    "TIE-Advanced-x1.png",
    "executor.png",
    "rebel-transport.png",
    "https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300",
    "https://picsum.photos/id/247/200/300",
    "https://picsum.photos/id/257/200/300",
    "https://picsum.photos/id/267/200/300",
    "https://picsum.photos/id/277/200/300",
    "https://picsum.photos/id/287/200/300",
    "https://picsum.photos/id/297/200/300",
    "https://picsum.photos/id/137/200/300",
    "https://picsum.photos/id/247/200/300",
    "https://picsum.photos/id/357/200/300",
    "https://picsum.photos/id/467/200/300",
    "https://picsum.photos/id/577/200/300",
    "https://picsum.photos/id/687/200/300",
    "https://picsum.photos/id/797/200/300",
  ];

  async getFilms() {
    const { page } = this.state;

    await fetch(`https://swapi.dev/api/starships/?page=${page}`)
      .then(async (res) => {
        let response = await res.json();
        const films = response.results.map((result,index) => ({name:result.name,image:this.posterImages[ index + 10 * (page - 1)], model:result.model, hyperdrive_rating:result.hyperdrive_rating}))
        this.state.data = [...this.state.data,...films]
        console.log(this.state.data)
        this.setState({})
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });


  }

  closeDetails() {
        document.getElementById("movie-details-wrapper").style.animation = "close .5s ease forwards";
        document.getElementById("bottom").style.animation = "open .5s ease forwards";
        document.getElementById("top").style.animation = "open .5s ease forwards";
        this.props.closeDetails();
    }


  componentWillMount() {
    this.getFilms();
  }

  componentDidMount() {}

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.page !== this.state.page) {
      this.getFilms();
    }
  }

  loadMore = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      page: prevState.page + 1,
      index: prevState.index + 1,
    }));
  };
  render() {
    const { isLoading } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="starships-wrapper">
        <div className="top" id="top">
          <img src="./logo.png" alt="logo" />
        </div>
        <div className="bottom" id="bottom">
          <ul>
            {this.state.data.map((res, index) => {
              return (
                <li
                  key={index}
                  className="ship-list"
                  style={{
                    backgroundImage: `url(${res.image})`,
                  }}
                >
                  <div className="name">{res.name}</div> 
                  
              //--------------after this part it doesn't work------//
                  
                  <div className="container">
                  <div className="overlay">
                    <p className="text">{res.model}</p>
                    <p className="text">{res.hyperdrive_rating}</p>
                    {/* <a href={`#state/${res.name}`} onClick={() => this.setState((res.url))} role="button">
                      More details &raquo;
                    </a> */}
                  </div>
                  </div>
            //--------------------------------------------------//
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="load-more">
          <button onClick={this.loadMore} className="btn-grad" variant="dark">
            {isLoading ? "Loading..." : "Load More"}
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Films;
```

```css
.starships-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.top {
    height: 400px;
    background-size: contain;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0) url("https://starwars.fandom.com/tr/wiki/Star_Wars?file=Star-wars-logo-new-tall.jpg") no-repeat top;
}

.top > img {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 10px 590px;
    text-align: center;
}

.bottom {
    background: #fff;
}

.bottom > ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: fit-content;
    margin: 0 auto auto;
    padding: 10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 6rem;
    color:#ffffff;
    bottom: 0;
    
}

.bottom > ul:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.ship-list {
    height: 510px;
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -9px black;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: bottom;
}

.name {
    background-color: #070707;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: 900;
    border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
}


  
  button {
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
      border: 2px solid #555555;
      background-color: #000000;
      /* Green */
      border: #070707;
      color: rgb(255, 251, 0);
      padding: 16px 32px;
      text-align: left;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 16px;
      margin: 4px 2px;
      transition-duration: 0.4s;
      cursor: pointer;
  }

@media only Screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .bottom > ul {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        width: 95%;
    }

    .movie-list {
        height: 350px;
        background-size: cover;
    }
}
   .ship-list .overlay {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: .5s ease;
        background-color: #008CBA;
      }
      
   .ship-list   .container:hover .overlay {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      
   .ship-list   .text {
        color: white;
        font-size: 20px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        text-align: center;
      }
```

Comment: Which hover is not working? You might also try adding `!important` to the CSS, as a last resort.

Comment: pardon. I forgot to mention which part. I edited the code by putting it between the comment lines. You can look again.

Comment: I tried **`!important`** but it didn't work

Comment: *field is a different color*? Do you have clashing styles? For example another stylesheet with the same class, but different CSS rules?

Comment: no i have only one style page

Comment: Hey @FeyzaSalgut , which react version are you using ?

Comment: But what should the hover color be? Your CSS doesn't change any colors based on a `:hover` selector.

Answer (score 0):

I main problem was using `hover` on multiple parent class. I've tried to do some changes to `styles.css` file.

Here is the codesandbox demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-sky-os2c3n?file=/src/styles.css

Though I have not made changes for media queries, so try to browse it above 900px media screen size.

### Demo Screenshot

[image]

Comment: What I want to do is exactly what you do. but I don't quite understand where you made changes :(

Comment: Try to observer the code, or you can try any text comparing tool like https://www.diffchecker.com/diff#editor. I majorly did changes inside styles.css, beside this, I just replaced componentWIllMount with componentDidMount. Hope this will help you :)

Comment: I SUCCESSED :D. thank you for your help